# Playing secure audio streams with HTML5 Audio

Tags: basic-authentication, html5-audio

Is it possible to play the protected streams with HTML5 Audio tag? The stream I'm playing is password-protected (HTTP Basic Authentication), how do I suppy the credentials? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am currently (2015) working on the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It looks like burakk solved it: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Playing-secure-audio-streams-with-HTML5-Audio/td-p/1716201

Answer (score 0):

Use special HTTP URL format http://username:password@example.com/your_stream in your **source** tags - this sends the credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header.

Comment: What if I don't have username and password, but I do have the Authorization bearer token?

Comment: @awe Authorization bearer token usually is passed in special HTTP header `Authorization: <your_token>`

Comment: but how can we attach this header on audio load?

Comment: You have no need to attach header, it’ll be attached automatically if you use such url form.

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov what do you do if the `Authorization` is JWT Bearer?

Comment: @nrofis If you need authorization with HTTP header you must do it with JS yourself, fetch audio data and feed html5 audio pleer with requested chunks (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)